# elasticsearch index size with and without _all

Tags: lucene, elasticsearch

Is there a way to find the size taken by individual fields in the index?

I have 10 fields and _source is disabled. I have no mapping for the fields.

With _all enabled the index size on disk was 95 mb

Without _all (disabled), the index size on disk was 70 mb

My understanding is _all stores a copy of all the fields. So wouldn't the index size be double with _all? Why would the difference be just 15 mb rather than 47mb?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`_all` is not a copy of all the fields; it is just another field which stores values of all other fields.

Let's say we have only three documents (`d1`, `d2` and `d3`) in the index with only two fields `f1` and `f2`. See below:

```
d1
{
    "f1": "v1",
    "f2": "v2"
},    
d2
{
    "f1": "v2",
    "f2": "v2"
},
d3
{
    "f1": "v1",
    "f2": "v1"
}
```

Now Lucene will store this data in inverted indices, something like below.

Inverted index for field `f1`:

```
"v1" -> "d1", "d3"
"v2" -> "d2"
```

Inverted index for field `f2`:

```
"v1" -> "d3",
"v2" -> "d1", "d2"
```

When `_all` is enabled, there will be an additional inverted index for the `_all` field.

Inverted index for field `_all`:

```
"v1" -> "d1", "d3"
"v2" -> "d1", "d2"
```

As you can clearly see, the posting list size without `_all` is 6 documents while posting list size with `_all` is 10 documents and not 12 documents.

This is just a simple example to prove that enabling `_all` does not mean that the index size will simply double up.

Comment: Very well answered. Thank you! So, if I search for the match query "v1 v2", its better to use _all rather than specify which fields to search because _all would at-least "theoretically" be faster because ES dont have to search the query multiple times for each field vs one in _all?

Comment: More than performance, this is about your requirements. If your intention is actually to search across all fields then by all means use `_all`. If your intention is to search across only a few fields, use `multi_match` query. If you want to search per field then use the field names explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to bsarkar's excellent answer, `_all` is an index-only field (by default, anyway).  That is, it is not stored.  A stored and indexed field, which would be any field that both can be searched and can be retrieved with a search result, must have an inverted index built, and must also be stored in a raw form in order to be retrieved later.  Storing the entire field contents can take up a very significant amount of storage.